# How to get attribute of the leaflet marker?

Tags: leaflet, jquery, markers, css

is there a way to get and hold the option attribute of the leaflet marker?

```
marker = L.marker([lat,lng], {draggable:true,icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: '', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'darkblue',html:(100)}) });
```

In the above marker, how will I able to get the option attribute of ther marker like jquery .css method. such as, How to get if the marker draggable is true or false, or html value (100) like the .CSS attribute of jQuery `$("#Div).css("color")`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you still have the reference to your `marker`, simply use `marker.options` to access the options object assigned to it. In your case: `marker.options.draggable`.

Comment: Wow.. thank you very much. you've save my day...:)